# Combining Merge and Insertion Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort

Is there a way to combine merge and insertion sort in such a way that the new algorithm is faster than each algorithm (merge and insertion sort) individually? I've been thinking about it for the past couple of hours but all I can come up with is once the division of the array in merge sort reaches a certain threshold (i.e. length of 10) then insertion sort kicks in and sort the array. But that won't make the algorithm faster it'll just reduce overhead. Any ideas regarding this?

Comment: timsort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort - very widely used, eg. in python's `sort()`

Comment: It will indeed make it faster. Insertion sort requires comparatively less operations than merge sort for lists of lengths less than a certain threshold.

Comment: Note that although Timsort uses a stack, it's a bottom up algorithm. Rather than use recursion, a single iterative pass splits up the array into runs of at least minrun size, where minrun is typically 32 to 64. It looks for natural non-descending runs (left <= right), and natural descending runs (left > right), reversing the descending runs. If the natural run size is less than minrun, then insertion sort is used to create a run of at least minrun size. A stack is used to keep track of run boundaries.

Comment: If there is enough memory space, then allocating a second working array the same size as the array to be sorted helps. For small runs of 64 or fewer elements, whether using insertion sort or merge sort on small runs depends if the data causes insertion sort to approach it's worst case time complexity of O(n^2).

Comment: On my system, sorting 16 million pseudo random unsigned 32 bit integers, insertion sort was about 7% faster with sub-run size set to 16 or 64 integers. For worst case insertion sort pattern of reverse order data , at sub-run size of 16, insertion sort was only about 1% slower, but with sub-run size of 64, about 55% slower. Wiki article mentions sub-run size of 10 elements, while Microsoft's std::stable_sort uses 32 elements for sub-runs.